# Liferay - Authentication without populating liferay db

Tags: liferay

Again, Do we have any possible solution that avoid populating liferay db with user information for authentication using extending methods/custom implementation/hooks/plugins/extensions?

Regards
Vishal G

Comment: What's the problem you want to solve with this?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to avoid creating a user in the Liferay database.  You can though create a dummy user that all users use or a dummy user for every user depending on your needs

Comment: Could you explain further how to create a dummy user that all users use?  From my experimentation I would need to have a user for each user I wish to use from my system.  The drawbacks with this are of course the obvious user sync overhead.

Comment: @broshb You can create a generic user with a known password e.g. "Liferay User" with password "LiferayPassword". Then all your users log in using that one user & password. However this is not an advisable approach because you can't audit what people have done etc etc

Answer (score 1):

It is generally not desirable to share accounts as you cannot benefit from all functionality regarding groups, personalization, ... This is basically why one would install a portal. 
To create users you can use Liferay's services.

If authorization is not your concern, it is possible to override the authenitaction mechanism with a variety of methods. THe authentication pipeline might be a good starting point.

http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/authentication-pipeline

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Liferay Hook to Authenticate using your custimization.
override the following jsp page.

> /html/portlet/login/login.jsp

Or you can create your own login portlet. No need to populate all users in db.
Just findUserById().
Dont forget to mention this change in portal-ext.properties file. You will need to specify custom Login portlet id.